# Symfony2 Dynamic/Dependent Forms

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form with 3 dependent fields:

Manufacturer -> ManufacturerProductGroup -> ManufacturerProductSeries

So I want to select a Manufacturer, based on the Manufacturer the ProductGroup and based on the ProductGroup the Product Series.

There is a CookBook Entry about how to deal with such dynamic forms an
it is easily working for the ManufacturerProductGroup. The problem is that
ManufacturerProductSeries depends on another dynamic form/field.

The problem is, that I cannot add an Listener in the closure since I have only 
access to the FormInterface not any more to the FormBuilderInterface.

I cant do it with just one listener as in the PRE_SET_DATA Listener since the form
would be submitted then which prevents any modification. I either need a way to add
the listener dynamically or maybe update just the data in the POST_SUBMIT listener
and not to replace the entire field/form.

This is the code which gives an error since I am adding a listener to a non existing
form field (manufacturerProductGroup is only available after the pre_set_data event)

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array                $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('manufacturer', 'entity', array('class' => 'ArticleBundle:manufacturer', 'empty_value' => false));

    $manufacturerProductGroupModifier = function(FormInterface $form, Manufacturer $manufacturer)
    {
        $manufacturerProductGroups = $this->em->getRepository('ArticleBundle:ManufacturerProductGroup')
            ->findAvailableByManufacturer($manufacturer);

        $form->add(
            'manufacturerProductGroup',
            'entity',
            array(
                'class' => 'ArticleBundle:ManufacturerProductGroup',
                'empty_value' => '',
                'choices' => $manufacturerProductGroups
            )
        );
    };

    $manufacturerProductSeriesModifier = function(FormInterface $form, ManufacturerProductGroup $manufacturerProductGroup)
    {
        $manufacturerProductSeries = $this->em->getRepository('ArticleBundle:ManufacturerProductSeries')
            ->findAvailableByManufacturerProductGroup($manufacturerProductGroup);

        $form->add(
            'manufacturerProductSeries',
            'entity',
            array(
                'class' => 'ArticleBundle:ManufacturerProductSeries',
                'empty_value' => '',
                'choices' => $manufacturerProductSeries
            )
        );

    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function(FormEvent $event) use ($manufacturerProductGroupModifier, $manufacturerProductSeriesModifier) {
            /** @var $article Article */
            $article = $event->getData();
            $manufacturerProductGroupModifier($event->getForm(), $article->getManufacturer());
            $manufacturerProductSeriesModifier($event->getForm(), $article->getManufacturerProductGroup());
        }
    );

    $builder->get('manufacturer')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function(FormEvent $event) use ($manufacturerProductGroupModifier) {
            $manufacturer = $event->getForm()->getData();
            $manufacturerProductGroupModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $manufacturer);
        }
    );

    $builder->get('manufacturerProductGroup')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function(FormEvent $event) use ($manufacturerProductSeriesModifier) {
            $manufacturerProductGroup = $event->getForm()->getData();
            $manufacturerProductSeriesModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $manufacturerProductGroup);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: have you found any solution for your question?

Comment: I found https://speakerdeck.com/webmozart/symfony2-forms-past-present-future to be a good source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the matter with the following code:

```
    $addManufacturerProductSeries = function (FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm()->getParent();
        $manufacturerProductGroup = $event->getData();

        $form->add(
            'manufacturerProductSeries',
            'entity',
            array(
                'auto_initialize' => false,
                'class' => 'ArticleBundle:ManufacturerProductSeries',
                'query_builder' => function (ManufacturerProductSeriesRepository $repository) use ($manufacturerProductGroup) {
                    return $repository->findAvailableByManufacturerProductGroupQueryBuilder($manufacturerProductGroup);
                },
            )
        );
    };

    $addManufacturerProductGroup = function (FormEvent $event) use ($factory, $addManufacturerProductSeries) {
        $form = $event->getForm()->getParent();
        $manufacturer = $event->getData();

        $fieldBuilder = $factory->createNamedBuilder(
            'manufacturerProductGroup',
            'entity',
            null,
            array(
                'auto_initialize' => false,
                'class' => 'ArticleBundle:ManufacturerProductGroup',
              'query_builder' => function (ManufacturerProductGroupRepository $repository) use ($manufacturer) {
                    return $repository->findAvailableByManufacturerQueryBuilder($manufacturer);
                },
            )
        );

        $fieldBuilder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, $addManufacturerProductSeries);
        $fieldBuilder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, $addManufacturerProductSeries);

        $form->add($fieldBuilder->getForm());
    };

    $builder->get('manufacturer')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, $addManufacturerProductGroup);
    $builder->get('manufacturer')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, $addManufacturerProductGroup);
```

Comment: this returns the error `option auto_initialize` doesn't exists. what this option do? and how i can implement it?

Comment: Maybe this option is deprecated. You should try remove it.