# validating dynamic forms in symfony2 returns "this value is not valid"

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, dynamic-forms

I have 3 entities: Country, State and City with the following relationships, and i have another entity named Location which have all of theme for setting user location,
i have a form too, for getting user's location data. which should be generated dynamically, because the entities are related to each other, and for example if the state changed, the cities must be changed too.

[image]

i used the code below in my listener for doing this:

```
/**
 * @param FormFactoryInterface $factory
 * @param EntityManager $om
 */
public function __construct($factory, $om)
{
    $this->factory = $factory;
    $this->om = $om;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FormEvents::PRE_BIND => 'preBind',
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData',
    );
}

/**
 * @param event FormEvent
 */
public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
{
    $company = $event->getData();

    if (null === $company)
    {
        return;
    }
    // company has country => edit action
    if($company->getCountry()){            

        //retrieve location
        $country = $company->getCountry();
        $state = $company->getState();
        $city = $company->getCity();

        if(is_object($state) && is_object($city) && is_object($country))
        {
            $states = $country->getStates();
            $cities = $state->getCities();
        }
        else
        {
            $cities = array();
            $states = array();
        }

    }else{
        // new location action
        $states = array();
        $cities = array();
    }

        $form = $event->getForm();
        $this->customizeForm($form, $cities,$states);

}

public function preBind(FormEvent $event)
{
    $dataForm = $event->getData();

    $countryId = $dataForm['country'];
    $stateId = $dataForm['state'];
    $cityId = $dataForm['city'];

    $country = $this->om
        ->getRepository('GMBundle:Country')
        ->find($countryId);
    $state = $this->om
        ->getRepository('GMBundle:State')
        ->find($stateId);
    $city = $this->om
        ->getRepository('GMBundle:City')
        ->find($cityId);

    if(is_object($state) && is_object($city) && is_object($country))
    {
        $states = $country->getStates();
        $cities = $state->getCities();
    }
    else
    {
        $cities = array();
        $states = array();
    }
    $form = $event->getForm();

    $this->customizeForm($form, $cities, $states);
}

protected function customizeForm($form, $cities, $states)
{
    $form
        ->add($this->factory->createNamed('state', 'entity', null, array(
                            'choices' => $states,
                            'label' => 'state',
                            'required' => true,
                            'empty_value' => 'choose state',
                            'class' => 'GMBundle:State',
                )))
        ->add($this->factory->createNamed('city', 'entity', null, array(
                'choices' => $cities,
                'label' => 'city',
                'required' => true,
                'empty_value' => 'choose city',
                'class' => 'GMBundle:City',
    )))
        ;
}
```

when i want to edit my form, i got the error `This value is not valid.`
it seems that symfony doesn't changed the data, for example if user had selected X as Stated and now wants to select Y for his state, symfony said the chosen city is not valid and must be selected from X's cities, which was his previous choice.

any idea how i can resolve it? or where i'm doing something wrong!?

-thanks

Comment: Did you try to debug your validation errors in your controller with `$form->getErrorsAsString()` This should give a first insight which field is responsible.

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás Yes! the message is **this value is not valid**

Comment: I understood, but the string output I mentioned above should explain which field is ***associated*** with the error. Unless the error appears on top of the form, then it is attached to the form itself.

Comment: Try replacing the `PRE_BIND` event with `POST_SUBMIT`

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás I can't do this, because i don't have `POST_SUBMIT`,
maybe because of my symfony version (i use 2.2)

Comment: That's an info worth mentioning. :) Try `POST_BIND` then.

Comment: sorry, you are right :)
now the error is `You cannot add children to a bound form` maybe i should replace `customizeForm` function with something else?

Comment: That means the you are adding a form element after the bound. You need to add the same form elements in your PRE_SET_DATA as well.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand your answer :(
what should i do in that function then!?

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás but i use same action (**customizeForm**) for both PRE_SET and POST_BIND..

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás thanks for your answers. i found the correct answer with your hint (POST_BIND) and the answer written here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904215/symfony2-dynamic-dependent-forms
:)
should i do something for your bounties!?

Comment: No worries, I couldn't provide a full working answer. Glad I could give you a nudge in the right direction.